# Вино-водочный или винно-водочный?

Tags: орфография

Как же правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: ВИННО-ВОДОЧНЫЙ (Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.)

Comment: Мясо-молочный?
У Лопатина правильно, не возражаю, но ничего не объясняет.

Comment: А причем здесь дефис? Автор сомневается не в дефисе, а в количестве Н.

Comment: Ларf, это мне вопрос?
Впрочем, отвечу. Дефис здесь ни при чем.
"Мясо-молочный" - исключение из правила. По общему правилу оно должно бы означать "относящийся к мясному молоку". И по этому же правилу "относящийся к мясу и молоку", "мясной и молочный" порождает не существующее в языке "мясно-молочный".

Кстати, просветите неграмотного. Вы "причем" в Вашем вопросе слитно по какому правилу пишете? Не сочтите за подначку.

Comment: Вопрос не к Вам, tmp, а ко мне. Как ни странно, я ответила не на тот вопрос. Поэтому его и удалила.

Comment: Вообще-то обычно пишу  не задумываясь. И в данном случае у меня даже и мысли не возникло написать по-другому. Но вот что в словаре:

ПРИЧЁМ I. местоим. нареч. Зачем, с какой стати. П. здесь эти люди? П. тут твоя работа? П. всё это? 

У меня именно в таком значении: с какой стати.

Comment: А почему тогда "ни при чем" - раздельно? Здесь то же самое значение.
Кстати, с "зачем" - "ни за чем" та же самая штука. Но тут как-то все естественно выглядит. "За()чем ты туда пошел"- это немого разные вещи в зависимости от орфографии. И по смыслу "ни за чем" - это как раз пара к "за чем", но не к "зачем".  
А вот с "при()чем" - и различий-то нет... Я боюсь даже сказать, сколько лет я добиваюсь ото всех внятного разъяснения. Ладно, спасибо, а то не по теме получается.

Comment: Согласна с вами.

Comment: @Ларf, простите, я не совсем понял. С чем тут можно соглашаться? С моим недоумением? Не стоит оно тотго, право слово. Или с тем, что не по теме? 
Ладно, еще раз спасибо в любом случае.

Comment: С чем согласна? Да с тем, что вполне логично: куда -  никуда, откуда - ниоткуда, причем - нипричем. Но последнее согласно правилам неверно, действительно, почему? Ведь каждое второе в паре слово явно образовано от первого с помощью НИ.

Answer (score 0):

Ой, где уж только не обсуждалось...
Винно-водочный - относящийся к ***вину и водке***.
Вино-водочный - относящийся к ***"винной водке"***.
Выбирайте, что Вам ближе.

Comment: Что такое винная водка?

Comment: http://popsop.ru/31097

К филологии это отношения не имеет, но вообще-то такое понятие было и раньше, хотя вряд ли кто-нибудь из писавших так, имел в виду его. Это, грубо говоря, вариации на тему бренди и чачи.    
В лучшем случае имеется в виду чача хорошего качества, с ярко выраженным букетом молодого вина.   
В одном худших из известных мне вариантов исходный водочный спирт добывается не из специальных бродильных материалов, а из вполне себе вина. Смысла в такой манипуляции немного, из ведра хорошего вина получается бутыль плохой водки. Понятно, что в магазинах этим пойлом не торгуют.